# How to tell if light switch box is grounded

Tags: electrical, grounding, installation

I'm attempting to install a smart light switch in an existing light switch box. There's isn't a ground wire I can see, nor does my voltage detector light up when I touch one end to hot and the other to the box. My outlets are all grounded, so could it be that my light switch box is not? This condo was built in 2004 in the Chicago area, so I imagine a ground of some kind must exist.

[image]

Comment: @GlenYates, not sure if you're suggesting that tongue-in-cheek or not, but to clarify for others finding this question: don't do this! A safer way is to test continuity to ground with an ohmmeter.

Comment: If you are doing the hot-to-box test properly, and it doesn't light up, then the box is not grounded.

Comment: I haven't been able to follow much of what's been said, however my contribution is this: if a wierd voltage is being read it may be a 'ghost voltage' arising from unintentional inductance of multiple a.c. conductors.

Answer (score 9):

### You have metal conduit connecting metal junction boxes.

All of it is ground.  The conduit, the boxes, all of it.  This is the ideal system.

Switches ground through the yokes and mounting screws. They don't need ground wires.

Receptacles are not allowed to do that unless they yoke has hard clean flush metal-metal contact with the box, and yours won't because the box is painted.  However, in the back of the junction box will be a hole that is tapped #10-32 for a ground screw.  Any #10-32 screw will do, but they sell little green ones very cheap.  Then you can just run a recep ground to the green screw.

Comment: Is it normal that I'm able to observe some voltage on the black wires even when I've turned off the circuit at the breaker?

Comment: @dfitzgerald possibly, there are 2 potential reasons for that, one harmless, one pretty bad.  Can you find which breaker de-energizes the black? Is it right next to this breaker?

Comment: So why did the empirical test fail? What are the chances of a botched installation where the conduit does NOT provide a good earth?

Comment: @MikeBrockington  I'm guessing he was testing a switched hot tht was off. Also, there's a question about which breakers de-energize the box so he might have been testing a dead circuit.

Comment: @Harper I found a separate breaker that de-energizes the black; it also turns off all the outlets in the room. I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but I uploaded a picture of my breaker box to https://imgur.com/a/gcF9h39. The breaker 9 turns off all the outlets in the living room and apparently also the black wire in the light switch box. The breaker 21 de-energizes the wires attached to the light switch itself. The light switch and subsequent light still work when only breaker 9 is shut off. What does this mean?

Comment: @dfitzgerald turn on all the lights powered by circuit 9 and plug a "load that is on" into every socket on circuit 9. Does that make the black wire hot indication go away?  If so, it's just phantom voltage from it running alongside circuit 21‘s hot.  But if not, then black is actually powered by circuit 21. Very important question: **Does black and red share a neutral?  If so, this situation is very bad and it's vital you open another question asking what to do about it**. Sharing a neutral isn't bad, it's where the breakers are.

Comment: @Harper I plugged something (fan, sonos speaker, etc) into every outlet on circuit 9, then shut off circuit 21 and was still able to observe voltage on the black wiring in the light switch box. I don't fully know how to tell if black and red share a neutral, so I drew up a crude diagram of what's in my box here: https://imgur.com/a/L5qx4mD I don't know where the wires are going once they leave the box.

Comment: @dfitzgerald ohhhhh.... Boy..... This is really looking like you better ask that question.  This is serious.  Post that drawing and the shot of your panel

Comment: What is the reason outlets can't do that but switches can?

Comment: @TTT I don't like guessing about research I haven't seen myself, but my wild-guess is a receptacle has to handle ground current *for anything plugged into it* which could be anything. A switch does not.

Answer (score 3):

Some of those wire compo's look strange so I'm guessing this in a conduit installation. the box should be grounded. Make sure you're going from box to always hot and not switched hot when testing for ground. Try reading from some of those black wires back in the box.

Comment: Yep, the block wires to the box is showing voltage, so the box is grounded. The black is showing voltage even after I turn off the power at the breaker, is that expected? Does that mean this is line? Or is it load?

Comment: What kind of voltage are you reading? Full 120V or somewhat less?

Comment: @Harper I only have a detector that shows either 120V or 220V (it was very cheap), but I'm seeing 120V

Comment: @dfitzgerald: If a hot wire has voltage in it after the circuit breaker is off then either you're switching off the wrong breaker or the breaker has failed into the unsafe mode due to an internal fault. Either way, figure out what is going on *before* you electrocute yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What is the third wire entering at the top left? Is that uninsulated copper? If so, it's a ground wire.

Comment: If you zoom in, it looks insulated, tan or brown.  Love the cat.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the device you took out had more than two wires on it.
Is /was it a three way switch or a switch plug combination??
How many screws (for wires) are on your new device?
From my 40 years at that trade, i would fire whoever made up that box.. The bare copper is surely grounded -- I just wonder where. Jim.

Comment: If you zoom in, that wire in the upper right isn't a bare copper ground and only a white and red wire have been  disconnected.  There are some shadows that look like wires.